# Decode JSON String

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm using SBJson and I know how to solve it when I have one key with one value, but how does it work when I have 2 keys and 2 values?

This is the string which needs to be decoded

```
    [{"ID":"1","Color":"Blue"},{"ID":"2","Color":"Red"},{"ID":"3","Color":"Green"}]
```

This is what I've tried

```
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [parser objectWithString:responseString];
    NSString *decodedJSON = [responseDict objectForKey:@"{\"ID\":\"Color\"}"];
```

It crashes at the last line.

Comment: What result would you expect for your decodedJSON? It looks like you're asking the responseDict for the object values for two keys at once or something, which simply won't work. Also, your responseDict is probably an NSArray since you've shown an array JSON string in the first code. Verify your return type of responseDict and then elaborate on what you're trying to make decodedJSON look like, a string like `@"1: Blue"` or what?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON object is an  `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`s. You have to iterate over the array or use indexes. For example, to get the first element (`{"ID":"1","Color":"Blue"}`):

```
[responseDict objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you want to iterate over all of them, use something like this (for example, to print them out in order):

```
for(NSDictionary* e in responseDict) {
  NSLog(@"%@", e);
}
```